# plotting a MeijerG function

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I'm trying to plot the following function on Wolfram Mathematica, but I get nothing on the graph! Why is that? Does anyone know why?

```
Plot[{1 - ((1/(Gamma[2])^4)*Sum[((4/y)^(-i - 1)*
(1/(i!*1.6^i)))*MeijerG[{{1.08 - i, -1.1 - i, -1 - i}, {}}, {{0, 2.1,2}, 
{}}, {2}], {i, 0, 5}])},{y, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, .1}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have curly braces where they shouldn't be, making the output of the function a nested list that *Mathematica* doesn't know how to plot. Furthermore, that plot range isn't going to work.  Do this:

```
f[y_] = 1 - ((1/(Gamma[2])^4)*Sum[((4/y)^(-i - 1)*(1/(i!*1.6^i)))*MeijerG[{{1.08 - i, -1.1 - i, -1 - i}, {}}, {{0, 2.1, 2}, {}}, 2], {i, 0, 5}];
Plot[f[y], {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: great, how can i make the scales in dB? @march

Comment: @dalia. Look up `LogPlot`,  `LogLogPlot`, `LogLinearPlot`.